# Custom logger not logging above warning level

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I am trying to include a custom logger in my application code to show all the messages for all the severity levels as the .py file will be packaged to .exe and logs would be the right place to trace the issue.

code

```
# Creating custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Creating handlers for the custom logger
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log', 'w')
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Creating formatter and adding it to handlers
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

logger.debug("DEBUG message from logger")
logger.warning("This is a warning message from logger.")
```

I am able to see the Warning message output but not the debug message though the level has been set to DEBUG

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a customer logger. If by that you mean you wrote your own logger code, you will have to investigate the code in the logger. There is nothing that can be seen from this example that anyone could use to help you.

Comment: Yes, I tried to create own logger instead of using the default root logger. I tried to follow the code that is provided https://realpython.com/python-logging/#classes-and-functions

Comment: Basic config works for the default root logger. To set level for the custom logger, you need to use handlers and that's what is done in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the severity level through basicConfig method for the custom logger after its initiation of the `class logger` throws an attribute error. This is expected as the custom logger should have it's own handler and formatter and can not be inherited from the root class.

```
AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'basicConfig'
```

The code to be run should be:

```
# Creating custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Creating handlers for the custom logger
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log', 'w')
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Creating formatter and adding it to handlers
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

logger.debug("DEBUG message from logger 2")
logger.warning("This is a warning message from logger.")
```

With this the loggin will also happen in the console. to avoid that, one needs to explicitly create a handler to set the level of severity for

```
StreamHandler
```